# What is the difference between Haml and Yaml in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, haml

I am a Ruby on Rails developer, working on this technology from past 7 months. while working on Rails many times i encountered `yaml` files.

As i encountered `yaml(yet another mark-up language)` is used to store the static content that needed to load before the server starts( like in `I18n` language translation ) and some are used as a switch to store `'boolean'` values.

Recently in some of SO questions i saw `haml` used in rails, As far as i know both are mark-up languages. What is the difference between these two and what to prefer and not-to while using rails.

Please shed some light on this :)

Comment: _"both are mark-up languages"_ – YAML Ain't Markup Language

Comment: That's what "YAML" stands for ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, thank you for clarification on `yaml` mark-up issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have nothing to do with each other.

HAML is a markup language for semi-structured documents. Its semantics are essentially equivalent to HTML, and its usage domain is the same. In addition, HAML is also a template language, it allows embedding of arbitrary code in a general-purpose programming language (typically Ruby), similar to ERb.

YAML is a data language. Its semantics are a bit higher-level than JSON (in fact, as of YAML 1.2, YAML is a proper superset of JSON, i.e. every JSON document is also a YAML 1.2 document) and somewhere below XML (as a pure data language, not a document markup language), but its usage domain is the same as both of those.

In short: HAML is a replacement for HTML (and ERb), YAML is a replacement for JSON and XML.

Answer (score 2):

Though `haml` and `yaml` sound very similar, they are actually very different. `yaml` is used to write configuration files while `haml` is used to output HTML.